# Escape user-generated content - What does that mean?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I am starting to use the [Share](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/) button from Google. I am actually using the Share link, and at some point in the docs it says this:

> Note: Replace {URL} with the URL of the page you want to share. You
>   must properly escape any user-generated content that may occur within
>   {URL}

What does that mean, and how can I escape this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape something means that you convert possible harmful characters into something that is not harmful for the computer to translate.

For example:

```
url = "<script>doSomeNastyStuff();</script>";
```

is a possible harmful string of contents. Mainly because youre storing plain javascript somewhere in your application.

When escaping this you're basically turning this into something not harmful at all.

Example:

```
url = "\"\x3Cscript\x3EdoSomeNastyStuff();\x3C\x2Fscript\x3E\"";
```

Now you've turned the harmful script into normal characters and when printed or stored you will not have to worry about a harmful script being injected into your code.

Other examples of escaping characters is this

```
var sayHello = "Hello "world", as you like to call yourself";
```

Now, this unescaped in javascript code would produce an error because the string has been terminated and the word 'world' is now a variable and then a new string starts.

This is the same string escaped to allow for quotation marks.

```
var sayHello = "Hello \"world\", as you like to call yourself";
```

And it's perfectly valid!

What Dillen suggests is exactly the right way for you to solve your problem but I thought explaining the escaping method would be appropriate as well.

Comment: What Dillen commented is encoding, but I would need to escape the characters, right? Is that the same?

Comment: You should be good with Dillens suggestion. Encoding does the same thing in this particular case! :)

Answer (score 0):

You must URL encode your URL, you can do this with any programming language.
For more information see: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/

**Javascript**

```
var url = encodeURIComponent("http://example.com");
```

**PHP**

```
$url = urlencode("http://example.com");
```

**C#**

```
var url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://example.com");
```