# Dynamic meta description apostrophe is replaced by &#x27; ASCII value

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, seo, html-encode

In my `meta`-`description` (which is dynamic), the apostrophe is replaced by `&#x27;` when I do <kbd>CTRL + U</kbd> / View source, and in Google Search.

```
<meta name="Description" content="Discover Sonam Kapoor&#x27;s look in Dolly Ki Doli, Dolly/Madhuri/Priya/Bhagyashree,Red Net Kameez with Patiala,Red Art Silk Patiala Suit,RITIKA SACHDEVA Gold finish"
```

It should be "sonam kapoor's" but I have "Sonam Kapoor&#x27;s". How to fix this?

I am using node.js, html, mongodb.

I did console.log in index.js and checked it is printing "Sonam Kapoor's" correctly so fetching from database correctly but in web page view source code it is coming "Sonam Kapoor &#x27;s" ASCII value.

Comment: How are you inserting the meta-description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi finally i solved it using following code

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('asciim', function(text) {
  text = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(text);
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

**Thanks everybody**

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid automatic HTML escaping by using the [`noEscape` option](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#base-compile) when compiling your Handlebars template:

`Handlebars.compile('{{foo}}', { noEscape: true })`

Be warned - this will be insecure if you are rendering any [user-generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700839/escape-user-generated-content-what-does-that-mean).